# Replace substring using REGEXP in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, regex

In my forum I have a BB code to display youtube videos.
following options can be used to extract youtube video code and use this code to build the embed code:

```
[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM&feature=related[/youtube]
[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM[/youtube]
[youtube]_OBlgSz8sSM[/youtube]
```

All these options return the youtube video code __OBlgSz8sSM

After upgrade to new version of forum the first two options with parsing of youtube link not working and only the last option with [youtube]_OBlgSz8sSM[/youtube] is work.

These BB codes are part of forum posts and not in separate field in database.

My goal is to replace all sub strings that start with [youtube] AND end with [/youtube] that contain ?v= with

```
[youtube]11 characters from ?v=[/youtube]
```

I am using MySQL
table name is POST
field name that contain these BB codes is PAGETEXT

Can you please assist me to build this update.

Comment: I don't think mySQL is equipped to do this - as far as I'm aware, its regular expressions are for selecting only, not replacing. Can't you use PHP or something to do the actual replacement?

Comment: In previous version of forum it was a module that did this parsing. This module is not available in new version and I am not programmer to write this module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Former answer was plain wrong.

Without using regex:

```
UPDATE POST SET PAGETEXT = REPLACE(PAGETEXT, '[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '[youtube]');
UPDATE POST SET PAGETEXT = REPLACE(PAGETEXT, '[youtube]www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '[youtube]');
UPDATE POST SET PAGETEXT = REPLACE(PAGETEXT, '[youtube]youtube.com/watch?v=', '[youtube]');
UPDATE POST SET PAGETEXT = REPLACE(PAGETEXT, '&feature=related[/youtube]', '[/youtube]');
```

This will remove the data you don't want through a direct search and replace. Are there any other patterns/formats that are not listed on the original post?

Using the test data:

```
SET @test = 'test [youtube]youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM&feature=related[/youtube] test';
SET @test = REPLACE(@test, '[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '[youtube]');
SET @test = REPLACE(@test, '[youtube]www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '[youtube]');
SET @test = REPLACE(@test, '[youtube]youtube.com/watch?v=', '[youtube]');
SET @test = REPLACE(@test, '&feature=related[/youtube]', '[/youtube]');
SELECT @test;

mysql> SELECT @test;
+------------------------------------------+
| @test                                    |
+------------------------------------------+
| test [youtube]_OBlgSz8sSM[/youtube] test | 
+------------------------------------------+
```

After running these four, it's interesting to run a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POST WHERE PAGETEXT LIKE '%?v=%';
```

and then ensure if there's anything else that needs handling.

Always test first.

Comment: @leon, thanks for the reply. I am afraid after applying that the [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM[/youtube] will be changed to [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch[youtube]_OBlgSz8sSM[/youtube]=_OBlgSz8sSM[/youtube] because you changing only the ?v= and not all the string that start from [youtube] and ends with [/youtube]

Comment: @Igal, no, it won't. The update works like this: (1) select all characters that are AFTER the delimiter (in this case, ?v=) so it wields _OBlgSz8sSM&feature=related[/youtube] then (2) get the FIRST 11 characters, wielding _OBlgSz8sSM then (3) prepend [youtube] and append [/youtube] to the string wielded in steps 1 and 2. ;-)

Comment: @leon, I have tested your suggestion. It replaced all the text in the column, not only from [youtube] to [/youtube]

Comment: "test [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM&feature=related[/youtube] test" replaced with "[youtube]_OBlgSz8sSM[/youtube]"

Comment: @Igal, my bad: you had already mentioned _These BB codes are part of forum posts and not in separate field in database._ I hope you did have a backup of it :-( I then assume there'll be N [youtube]_url_[/youtube] within each PAGETEXT field. I'll be updating by answer in a few minutes to support this.

Comment: @leon, it is works now. It cover most of formats. I can deal with remaining. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Igal, anytime. Sorry for the first mess.