# replace string in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I would like to replace `"|"` with `"_"` in mysql if meets the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content REGEXP 'text\\(584\\|([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\|([a-zA-Z0-9_])'
```

so if finds for example `text(584|g345|2344` should look at the end  `text(584_g345_2344`

Is it possible if I use REGEXP to find matches?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
REPLACE(text_string, from_string, to_string)
```

More info can be found in [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

**EDIT:**
However, you cannot mix `REGEX` and `REPLACE`.
You'll need to have it done with several queries, have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6397285/1031900)?